# Why does my Android Eclipse Emulator never launches?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, launch

I have Eclipse with Android set up. The problem is when ever I run a project from eclipse to test it, the application never launches and the emulator never shows up. Even though the launching progress bar shows 100%.

Comment: Check your run configurations. Make sure your project is connected to the emulator

Comment: Its launches for 2 or 3 times, then after that i have to restart to get it run

Comment: That's highly relevant to your question..

Comment: what is the size you have given in your AVD keep it approximately 512MB  ?

Comment: @RMH how to create AVD in titanium i dont know

Comment: My problem is same can you help me @RMH ...

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160100/android-emulator-is-running-but-app-is-not-launching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the AVD's memory is set to 512, if it's higher the emulator will get a memory heap error and fail. Also try to enable verbose output when building, this can be set from within the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a device attached? Eclipse switches to mobile devices automatically

Comment: No I dont have a device attached

Answer (score 0):

I had once or twice had such problem. Restart of eclipse worked for me. And Yes also check the Run configuration, make sure your project is linked with emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window->Preferences->Android->Build and select verbose build output

Now run your project and check Android console. In my case there were thousands of 
"Dx processing %classname%..." which took several minutes to finish. 
Just to make it clear: dx.bat is an ADT utility program, it converts multiple Java class-files to single "classes.dex" file(Dalvik executable file). 
I had a project which used several libraries with lot of classes and the compilation was very fast(several seconds), but the launching was quite slow(2-4 minutes).
Then I found out that the most time consuming part was converting class files from my project and from all third-party libraries to *.dex file(the resulting size of dex-file was about 4 Mb). As far as I know, it's impossible to attach libraries to android project without dexing their class-files, so you have to be patient during launching your project.

UPD: It's possible to strip all unused code from your application.
Please check this link: [Always running proguard before Android dex'ing in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320998/always-running-proguard-before-android-dexing-in-eclipse)